# Azure Blob Storage Acquire Lease throws an error when time lease time more than 1 minute

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have am trying to acquire lease on a blog but it gives me a `400 Bad Request`. If the time span is more than 1 minute.

Is this expected? I am not able to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally, blob leases were simply 60 seconds. Starting with the 2012-02-12 version, blob lease durations can be between 15-60 seconds, or infinite. You can read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/new-blob-lease-features-infinite-leases-smaller-lease-times-and-more.aspx) for more details around all the updates in the 2012-02-12 update.

If you want to see the actual REST API details behind the SDK, it's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691972.aspx). In this page, you'll see that an infinite lease duration is specified as `-1` (which is slightly different from, say, the .net SDK call,  which uses `null` to signify infinite lease).

Comment: Spent a lot of time trying to understand why 90 sec doesn't work cause was getting just 'bad request' response.